# How can Ted show a finger?

Tags: ted

In [Ted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_%28film%29), When the news shows Ted being arrested at an airport. Ted gives the camera the rude finger. When he does this, his hand is censored. Ted doesn't actually have any fingers then how would he have been able to show a finger?

Comment: Are you asking HOW Ted could give the finger given that his hands are stuffed mitts, or WHY the TV station report bothered to blur it?

Comment: How ted could give the finger? @AnkitSharma

Comment: That's the whole point of the joke.

Comment: You're probably not understanding the comedy. There is no how, just that it is. Sometimes "You just have to let the art flow over you."

Comment: I understanding the comedy but I am just little bit curious about things. @wbogacz

Comment: The point is, if you understand it is the "rude finger", you've gotten the point. Whether the stuffed animal can actually accomplish it is irrelevant.

Comment: The more interesting question is how Ted can have sex without an "eleventh finger" ;)

Answer (score 5):

Ted's paws are shown throughout the film as being very prehensile. He can:

1. Hold a bong
2. Use a cigarette lighter
3. Drink from bottles with one hand
4. Use a cash register
5. Use a telephone keypad
6. Use a television remote

Among other complex hand tasks.

It is conceivable that if he were to point his paw in a certain manner at a person or a camera that the gesture could be perceived as him giving the "finger" (technically the paw) to the viewer. In the scene where he does (he's being detained at an airport) it is clear that he is also complaining very loudly and cursing , so it a gesture with his paw might be seen as him flipping off the camera.